# Live filter on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, cifilter

How can i add filters to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? Ive tried making a CIFilter and settings AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.filters property to an array with the filter, but it did nothing.